# Export to CSV not same as table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to download table data into a CSV format. The data in one of the fields contains ",". 
Eg: Doe, John

When I download the csv file, the data after comma is shifted to next column. But I want the entire data i.e including comma in same column.

The Code I used as follows:

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
//header to give the order to the browser
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=download.csv');
//select table to export the data
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tablename";
$select_table=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_table);

if ($rows)
{
getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows)
{
 getcsv($rows);
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_table);
 }

  // get total number of fields present in the database
 function getcsv($no_of_field_names)
 {
   $separate = '';


  // do the action for all field names as field name
  foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name)
 {
 if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name))
 {
  $field_name = '' . str_replace('<em>', '', $field_name) . '';
  }
  echo $separate . $field_name;

 //sepearte with the comma
 $separate = ',';
  }

//make new row and line
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Can someone help me get through this issue.
Thanks

Comment: if `, ` is the separaor of the CSV, you have to escape every `, `, or quote the whole string, so `John, Doe` becomes `"John, Doe"`

Comment: i suggest not reinventing the wheel- use `fputcsv`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you escape the `,`. Typically values that contain sensitive characters (such as `,` and `\n`) are surrounded in `"`.

So your output can be:

```
 "Doe, John",52,New York
```

You can either write your own escape function or use PHPs [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv). It writes to a file handler that's a bit inconvenient but you can make it `stdout`.

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdout");
fputcsv($handle, array("Doe, John", 52, "New York"));
```

Comment: I understood that I have to escape comma but unable to figure out how to do it in the above code. Could you elaborate for the above code? Thanks!

Comment: You escape a `,` by surrounding the value in double quotes. There is no escape sequence like `\,`.It's similar to `$foo = "bar;";`, that first `;` is part of the string, not the end-of-statement. `fputcsv` has this escape rule and more, so it will always output valid CSV.